# Jmeter test Restful web services with files upload

Tags: java, spring, file, rest, jmeter

I would like to use Jmeter to test my Restful web services but I have a problem with file upload.
This is the method signature

```
public @ResponseBody Response uploadFiles(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user, @RequestParam("file[]") MultipartFile[] file, @RequestParam("fileType") String fileType, @RequestParam("idCar") Integer idCar, @RequestParam("initialKm") Integer initialKm, @RequestParam("idAcquisition") Integer idAcquisition);
```

and I have configured Jmeter like below:
[image]

this is for the file

[image]

I receive this stacktrace from tomcat (I figured out this exception is thrown *after 5-6 seconds and not immediately*):

```
2016-09-13 12:07:08 - org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:225)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:368)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:308)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:61)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:351)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1131)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:465)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:390)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestWrapper$FirewalledRequestAwareRequestDispatcher.forward(RequestWrapper.java:139)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl.handle(AccessDeniedHandlerImpl.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have compared Jmeter request and browser request and they seem equals. With postman I have the same error.
Do you know where is the problem? Thanks

**UPDATE**: maybe it doesn't work because I use form authentication instead in other web sevices I use basic authentication

Answer (score 0):

> Request method 'POST' not supported

My guess is that your application expects [HTTP PUT request](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6) and you are sending POST.

Also given `Restful` web service, I would expect that you need to send request a little bit differently. See [Testing REST API File Uploads in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-advanced-rest-api-file-uploads-jmeter) for examples of uploading files to Google Drive using [Google Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk) POST and PUT methods.

Comment: My web service is POST, maybe the problem is array of MultipartFile.
I wouldn't like to change my web service or write adapter for it but I don't know how to make it works

Answer (score 0):

Changing the implementation field value from HttpClient4 to Java should solve this problem.